# Architecture for cross platform messaging app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, backend, ejabberd, google-cloud-messaging

i am looking to build a mobile messaging app firstly in android and then ios later, and am struggling with the backend architecture and need some advice on what would be best in my circumstance. Basically i am used to just developing apps through a basic web server and using mysql with php, but now i think and want to create something that not only is very reliable and fast but is also scalable and can be used by both the android and ios platforms.

I am thinking about developing it on google cloud platform using either their google app engine or google compute engine depending on what other architectures i use. Also i was going to use google cloud messaging as my main way of handling the messages, however i am now not sure of that as it is only supported by apps that run on android and not ios, also i have heard it can be unreliable in some messages getting lost.

My main problem is that i have heard so many things about different architectures like ejabberd, xmpp, socket i.o and databases like redis that all work well with messaging apps, however i am not sure which to go that will work well together.

Sorry if this seems a bit of a confused situation, but i dont want to start developing something that i am later going to have to change. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Announced last week: Engage your users across Android, iOS and Chrome via **Google Cloud Messaging 3.0:**

- https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJatfdattno

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can it be used for messaging or is it still mainly used just for notifications and send to sync?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about many different things.

- Storage: can be a mysql database or something like mongo db
- Transport protocol: XMPP is a chat protocol with many chat features included but it is not supported in browsers. WebSocket is more low level and more general but works inside the browser
- webserver software: you basically need access to the database and be able to transmit XMPP or WebSocket. I'd recommend node.js for this. PHP is more for web pages

Comment: XMPP is supported in browsers when using bosh refer this link http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html

Comment: He can use Ratchet ( PHP )